# Unhandled exception at 0x75cd9617 (KernelBase.dll)

Tags: c++, visual-studio, kinect, point-cloud-library, openni

I have made win console application project in visual studio 2010. It is a PCL sample code for OpenNI_Grabber.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IE7vk.png)

Above is the snapshot of error I am getting.

```
#include<pcl\visualization\cloud_viewer.h>
#include<pcl\io\grabber.h>
#include<pcl\io\openni_grabber.h>
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>
#include<windows.h>

using namespace pcl;
using namespace std;

 class SimpleOpenNIViewer
 {
   public:
     SimpleOpenNIViewer () : viewer ("PCL OpenNI Viewer") {}

     void cloud_cb_ (const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::ConstPtr &cloud)
     {
       if (!viewer.wasStopped())
         viewer.showCloud (cloud);
     }

     void run ()
     {
       pcl::Grabber* interface = new pcl::OpenNIGrabber();

       boost::function<void (const pcl::PointCloud<pcl::PointXYZRGB>::ConstPtr&)> f =
         boost::bind (&SimpleOpenNIViewer::cloud_cb_, this, _1);

       interface->registerCallback (f);

       interface->start ();

       while (!viewer.wasStopped())
       {
         boost::this_thread::sleep (boost::posix_time::seconds (1));
       }

       interface->stop ();
     }

     pcl::visualization::CloudViewer viewer;
 };

 int main ()
 {
   SimpleOpenNIViewer v;
   v.run ();
   return 0;
 }
```

Comment: Do some debugging. Don't use Stack Overflow as a debugger. Please learn to format code also. Note the edit I made to the question.

Comment: Also, please don't post screenshots without posting the error message as searchable text.